# Passing multiple dimension array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

MySql query returns me a multi-dimensional array :

```
function d4g_get_contributions_info($profile_id)
{
   $query = "select * from contributions where `project_id` = $profile_id";
   $row = mysql_query($query) or die("Error getting profile information , Reason : " .    mysql_error());
   $contributions = array();
   if(!mysql_num_rows($row)) echo "No Contributors";

   while($fetched = mysql_fetch_array($row, MYSQL_ASSOC))
   {
       $contributions[$cnt]['user_id'] = $fetched['user_id'];
       $contributions[$cnt]['ammount'] = $fetched['ammount'];
       $contributions[$cnt]['date'] = $fetched['date'];
       $cnt++;  
   }
   return $contributions;
}
```

Now I need to print the values in the page where I had called this function. How do I do that ?

Comment: read about foreach, and then you can do foreach inside another foreach.

Comment: mamdouh alramadan,

Could you please help me further with this, I tried applying nested for_each loop but with no progress.

Comment: dont you  need to assign the value of $cnt++ = 0  first ?

Comment: Thanks Everyone but I solved it

   foreach ($contributions as $contributor => $property)
    {
      foreach ($property as $property_name => $property_value)
       {
         echo 'Contributor ' .$contributor .':'.$property_name . $property_value;
         }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the function like this:

```
while($fetched = mysql_fetch_array($row, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
$contributions[] = array('user_id' => $fetched['user_id'],
                            'ammount' => $fetched['ammount'],
                            'date' => $fetched['date']);

}

return $contributions;
```

Then try below:

```
$profile_id = 1; // sample id
$result = d4g_get_contributions_info($profile_id);
foreach($result as $row){
    $user_id = $row['user_id']
    // Continue like this
}
```